# Changing NGUI UILabel vertical linespacing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uilabel, ngui

Im using a .ttf font in an NGUI UILabel, and am having some weird issues with the line spacing of the font.

If I use the font in 'microsoft paint', I get no vertical line spacing issues whatsoever...

However, when I use the font in an NGUI UILabel the vertical line spacing seems to decrease, 'scrunching' the text together if you will.

Has anyone run into this issue? I have tried editing the font spacing values using 'FontForge' but no difference has been made.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've run into that problem, so I'm curious what settings you used when importing the font.

NGUI's label will read default spacing information from the `UIFont` object that you created during import. Recommend you find that asset in your project panel, then adjust a setting.

Quoting [the docs](http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=133):

> **Spacing** lets you adjust the distance between printed characters (X) and lines (Y).

The docs don't specify what unit spacing uses, but it seems to be in pixels.

Comment: its a .ttf dynamic font.  There aren't many settings to adjust in the editor.

Comment: Ah, apologies for missing that detail. In that case, I'd recommend importing the font so that you *can* adjust those settings. My impression is that NGUI's support for dynamic fonts is limited.